# Неправильное отображение трехмерных объектов в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Я работаю в JavaFX с трехмерной графикой. Создал сцену, расположил объекты в сцене.
Однако при определенном обзоре объект, который был добавлен в сцену на задний план, перекрывает объекты на переднем плане.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включить буфер глубины и тест по нему (обычно используется "ближе или равно"). Ключевые слова - `DepthWrite`, `DepthTest`, `DepthFunc`, `DepthCompare`.